# Generating values from a probability density function

Tags: random-number-generator, monte-carlo

If I have a probability density function, some f(x) which is >= 0 everywhere and integrates to 1, is there a method to generate random numbers using that PDF?

I know there is the box-muller transform to convert uniform random numbers to gaussian, but is there anything for the general case, or at least a more general case of PDFs?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66133/755?  Or is it different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can integrate the PDF to a CDF F(x), then uniformly generate a random number x between 0 and 1 and choose a y such that F(y)=x as your sample. This is more or less difficult, depending on your PDF. Some PDFs have analytical solutions, others need numerical methods. For some distribution [Rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) works well, some distributions can be sampled from using a suitably constructed [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo).

See also [this set of slides](http://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/stat/Distributions/DrawingRandomSamples/DrawingSamples.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to write this up: https://blog.demofox.org/2017/08/05/generating-random-numbers-from-a-specific-distribution-by-inverting-the-cdf/